# MongoDB, Mongoose. Проверить существует ли объект в БД. Если нет, то добавить, если да, то пройти мимо

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Доброго времени суток!
Есть Mongo БД, в которую добавляются данные полученные get-запросом. Get-запрос посылаю каждые 10 секунд.
Теперь, собственно, вопрос: данные добавляются каждый раз после отработки запроса, тем самым в БД много повторяющихся объектов. Как реализовать проверку в БД, в ходе которой будут просматриваться уже существующие объекты в базе по (в данном случае) `tenderId`: если таковых не будет, то будут добавляться, а если такие уже есть, то "проходим мимо".

Вот мое решение на данный момент:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("libs/mongoose");

let tender = new mongoose.Schema({
    tenderId: String,
    tenderDate: String
});

let Tenders = mongoose.model("Tenders", tender);


const request = require("request");

let offset = new Date().toISOString();
let url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${offset}+02.00`;

function getTenders(time) {
    time = new Date().toISOString();
    url = `http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=${time}+02.00`; // меняю время каждые 10 секунд и отправляю гет запрос
    request(url, {json: true}, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        let tendersList = []; //создается массив объектов
        body.data.forEach(function (item) {
            let tendersData = new Tenders({
                tenderId: item.id,
                tenderDate: item.dateModified
            });
            tendersList.push(tendersData); //кладу объекты, полученные с сервера, в массив объектов
            Tenders.insertMany(tendersList) // кладу весь массив в базу
                .then(item => {
                    console.log("Saved to db")
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw new Error;
                });
            // console.log(`Tender id:${item.id}`);
            // console.log(`Tender data:${item.dateModified}`);
        });
    });
}

getTenders();
setInterval(getTenders, 10000);
```

Я так понимаю, что необходимо получать все айдишники, которые есть, потом айдишники, которые уже есть в базе, сравнить, каких нет и их положить в БД, но я сомневаюсь, что это правильный ход мыслей.